# SHOW Error when API call takes too much time based on setTimeout or $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a setup in which I am calling an API for data which is based on date selected. Now my issue is if a daterange is selected for which if API does not have data *(net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)* --- it does not respond instantly (API call takes a lot of time on server end to respond -- that there's no data), thereby I am unable to show a message on my screen that there is no data present in here.

Any fix I can do with $timeout ?  that if there's no response till 3 seconds we show that there's no data and stop the APICall.

```js
$scope.loadChart = function(startDate, endDate, appKey, type){
                    
                    d3.json(APICall, function (error, data) {
          
                     if(!data){
                        console.log("ERROR shown");
                    } 
                    else {
                   
                        svg.selectAll("*").remove();
                        svg1.selectAll("*").remove();
                        $rootScope.plotDonutChart(data, callID, arc, arcOver,pie,pie1,svg, svg1, width, color);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Its not ideal to fix this in client side. You should fix the server code. I don't know why your server is taking long time if there is no data. Ideally it should replay quickly if no data. So you have to check the server side code and fix this issue.

Comment: I know it is not ideal fix, but I have to make that work for sometime, server will only show data - if there is data.

Comment: but if there is data and your API takes more than 3 seconds, your solution is wrong, you have to rely on the actual server answer. If you can't fix server speed in this case, add a loading icon to warn that it is in progress?

Comment: i agree thats absolute bad design, your serverside code should send an answer you can parse, imagine users on slow internet connection where the request may take more than 3 seconds even if there is data

Comment: @johnSmith - I completely agree but I want to make this thing work for temporary purpose.

Comment: The observations by @KiranB and others make total sense. This must be handled on the server side. For now, until your data gets loaded, you can show a loader with 'Date range for which data is not available may take longer to respond' message or something of that sort to the user, letting them know, why it is taking more time.

Answer (score 0):

as you stated in the comments above you want a temporay purpose answer

d3.json is equivalent to d3.request and it takes a timeout option

https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json

https://github.com/d3/d3-request

https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/src/request.js#L74

i dont  know angular and d3 but you may transform your code to sth like:

```
// sets timeout to 500 ms
d3.request(url)
.timeout(500)
.mimeType("application/json")
.response(function(xhr) { return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); });
```